Use Non-Consumables to increase permanent limit multiple times
I'm launching an app with a freemium model where users can purchase additional storage increments. The limit should sync across devices and restore after reinstallation.
I'm using non-consumable since the increase is permanent. But the non-consumable can only be purchased once, so I created a similar non-consumable product ID for each increment and only present one at a time:
increase_limit_by_100_1
increase_limit_by_100_2
increase_limit_by_100_3
etc.

Is there a better way to implement this? The repeated product IDs don't feel like the most clean implementation.

The best way is to introduce a subscription service. Where the user subscribes to a particular product. In this way, you can also keep track of purchases. Using non-consumable, you cannot keep track since the product is only purchased once.

Subscription can be an alternative, but I'm unsure if there is a "best way" regarding pricing in this case. In my case, it's a local first app, and since I'm not running a backend, some would say that subscription models should come with running costs.

Yes, the subscription model needs a backend but that will not cost much. Maybe a few dollars a month if you use Firebase.

Alright, here’s the play.
You’re trying to manage an escalating system where users upgrade in increments, right? But instead of overcomplicating the structure with redundant product IDs, you focus on controlling the flow. There’s a way to design this so the app manages what’s available, tracks progress, and handles limits seamlessly across devices.
Think about it: the user doesn’t need to see every option upfront, just what’s relevant at the time. And when they reinstall or switch devices, their progress is still there, synced and intact. It’s about using smart thresholds and ensuring every move feels intentional—not scattered.
You already have the tools to make this work. You just need a system that adapts as they level up. Simple, efficient, and completely under your control.
